# Problems animating a button w/jQuery: doesn't hide

Tags: jquery, css

Everything works pretty well in this animation till the last bit. I've made a [CodePen](http://codepen.io/houwat/pen/BLNdAo), and also inserted the jQuery code below.

When I click on the second button, the text area comes out animated. When I click on the text area to close it up, it does a final "appear" before disappearing completely. I tried to add an opacity property in the closing animation (CSS file), but it doesn't seem to be enough. Any ideas?

```
$(document).ready();

$('#button2d').click(function() {
   $('.price_description').removeClass("swiftin");
   $('.price_description').addClass("open");
   $('.price_description').show();
   $('#button3d').fadeOut(080);
});

$('.price_description').click(function() {
   $('.price_description').removeClass("open");
   $('.price_description').addClass("swiftin");
   $('#button3d').fadeIn('slow', function() {
      $('.price_description').css('display', 'none');
   });
});
```

Comment: use .hide();. http://api.jquery.com/hide/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add to the .swiftin class   `animation-fill-mode: forwards;` in order to stop your animation on the last frame:

```
.swiftin {
  animation: swiftin 0.5s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
```

Comment: Question: so without the animation-fill-mode, the text area will go back to its previous/initial state?

Comment: Yes. The default value of `animation-fill-mode` parameter is `none;`, that means that the animation will not apply any styles to the target before or after it is executing. 
You can read more about this property on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-fill-mode)

Answer (score 0):

add hide(); after removeClass("open")

```
$(document).ready();

$('#button2d').click(function() {
    $('.price_description').removeClass("swiftin");
   $('.price_description').addClass("open");
   $('.price_description').show();
   $('#button3d').fadeOut(080);
});

$('.price_description').click(function() {
    $('.price_description').removeClass("open").hide();
 $('.price_description').addClass("swiftin");
$('#button3d').fadeIn('slow', function() {
     $('.price_description').css('display', 'none');
  });
});
```

P.S.`$(document).ready();` is wrong, check the documentation

Comment: Thanks. I'll check the documentation too.

Comment: Is it because I don't need to load anything after the document is open?

Comment: wrong syntax, it should be like:   
$( document ).ready(function() {
 ...put functions here...
});